# Error while inflating class ripple

Tags: android, android-actionbar, rippledrawable

I am trying using ripple on my action bar tabs i.e when action bar are clicked then it shows ripple. but IT IS NOT WORKING. Here's my code snippet.
I am providing code of colors.xml and my custom_bg.xml. I have one more file style.xml

```
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    String value = tab.getText().toString();
    Log.d("You Selected", value);

    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Messages")) {
        tab.setCustomView(R.drawable.custom_bg);//Here it shows error
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:openTabPage('mobilePageMessagesNavLink');", null);

    } 

  custom_bg.xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" >
  </ripple>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorHighlight">#FF6600</color>
</resources>
```